# 500 internal servor error with parent canvas woo theme at host server

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, woocommerce, woothemes

I am using the Canvas WordPress theme (by WooThemes.com) and successfully made a child-theme to override my CSS. Now from few days My hosting server gives 500 internal server error for accessing any php files from canvas theme. The shortcodes and css generator.php files and all other php files are not working. I am stuck to use any canvas theme feature. please help me out.

Comment: What do the server logs tells you? Do you have [debugging information](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with permission of **parent folder** its 777 in linux hosting.changing it to 755 resolve the error.